# FATAL ERROR: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am trying to start with OOP cause it seems to be much better then the way i used to code, but now i am trying to create a mysql connection class and i receive the same error over and over again.

I use 2 classes 1 for the connection and the other for the queries.

Class users (queries)

```
class Users{
protected $_userid, $_username, $_lastLogged, $_rank, 
$_driverLicense, $_experience, $_maxExperience, 
$_cash, $_vehicle, $_residence, $_weapon, $_tool, 
$_memberSince, $_about;

var $con;

function getConnection($con){
    return $this->$con;
}

function checkLogin($username, $password){
    $stmtCheckLogin = $this -> getConnection() -> prepare('SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `username` = ? ');
    $stmtCheckLogin -> bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmtCheckLogin -> execute();
    $stmtCheckLogin -> bind_result($id, $password);
    $stmtCheckLogin -> store_result();
    $stmtCheckLogin -> fetch(); // just a test to see if everything is working correctly
    echo $id. "<br/>";
    echo $password;
}

 }
```

Class db(connection)
    class db{

```
function getCon(){
    $con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mafioso');
    if(!$con){
        throw new Exception('Could not connect to database..');
    }else{
        return $con;
    }
}

function __destruct(){
    $this -> getCon() -> close();
}
}
```

And this is how i try to call them

```
<?php require_once('classes/User.php'); require_once('classes/db.php');

    $db = new db;
    $user = new Users();
    $user -> getConnection($db -> getCon());
    if(!isset($_SESSION['checkLogin']) || ($_SESSION['checkLogin'] == 0)){


    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $user -> checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    }
    ?>
```

And this is the error I keep receiving:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in classes\User.php on line 12
```

Comment: What is line 12 of your User.php file?

Comment: This is line 12 'return $this->$con;'

Comment: Please dont write `$obj -> method/attribute`. Write `$obj->method/attribute`.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Is there a good reason for not doing so? (Because to me using spaces just looks strange, but I can't see why it could cause issues)

Comment: Okay i will in future but do you know what causes this error?

Comment: @Anwar . Just common code standards. You wrote that you just stared with OOP. Best not to have any bad habits from the beginning. You can read more about the standards here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->$con;` should be `$this->con;`.

The whole method seems to be a getter / setter hybrid which will not work.

There are getter methods to get a property like:

```
function getConnection() {
    return $this->con;
}
```

and setter methods to set the value of a property like

```
function setConnection($con) {
    return $this->con = $con;
}
```

`$this` is the current class you are into. With `->` you can address methods and/or properties. But you don't need to write the `$` again cause the `$this->` implies already that it is a variable or method.

Other hints for well don OO:

- Give your properties scopes like `public`, `private` or `protected`.
- Write `$this->obj` and not `$this -> obj`
- Don't call getter methods like `getConnection()` in the own class. You can just use `$this->con` instead

Comment: why should you write `$obj->method` instead of `$obj -> method`? To me, the second is much more clear / readable... But maybe it's just me...

Comment: @Mathlight because it's a variable/method selector and one statement and you don't have spaces in them. You also don't write `$ obj`. There is no open source project I'm aware of which uses `$obj -> method` style.

Comment: Alright, your right about that... You don't find it a lot in projects. And if i recal it right it is indeed some kind of coding standard to not use an space. But still.. It is better readable... ( i think )

Comment: That's your opinion I don't want to destroy it so do it if you love to be a rebel ;-)

Comment: Haha, Don't worry about that ;-) But I like to hear other thoughts about things that we just do, just because we always did it that way. Sometimes you can get interesting points of views on the topic which will let you look into it very different.

Comment: I think I'm a none-space user because PHP OO is heavily impacted by Java OO (and I learned OO with Java) and in Java you can't even write `obj . method` (afaik).

Comment: I for one do not think it more readable to have spaces. And in fact, it makes it clearer *not* to have spaces, as it makes it very clear that the property or method is **attached** to the object

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the `getConnection` method:

```
function getConnection($con){
    return $this->$con;
}
```

This returns the property with the name that `$con` contains. 
I.e. if `$con = 'foo';` then this method will return `$this->foo`.

In your case PHP is trying to convert the connection into a string so that it can access the appropriate property. mysqli objects cannot be converted to a string so the fatal error is thrown.

Likely you want a setConnection that correctly sets the connection and a getConnection which returns con.

Try:

```
function getConnection(){
    return $this->con;
}
function setConnection($con){
    $this->con = $con;
}
```

Comment: But i dont set the $con in the same class. I set $con in the db class. I only want to get it from that class :)

Comment: @Anwar Sorry I should have been clearer. When calling the user initially you would do: `$user->setConnection($db->getCon());` after that, all calls in $user can just use `$this->getConnection()`

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code is wrong:

```
function getConnection($con)
{
    return $this->$con;
}
```

Because you're giving getConnection a mysqli-instance. So in `$this->$con` it trys to convert `$con` to a string, but `$con` is a mysqli instance.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
function setConnection($con)
{
    $this->con = $con;
}

function getConnection()
{
    return $this->con;
}
```

Because you're using `$this->getConnection()` in `checkLogin()`.